# Valores duplicados armando un JSON

Tags: php, json

Tengo problemas al armar un JSON el cual tiene 2 lineas de productos, debe quedar asi:

```
"credit_note_lines": [
    {
        "unit_measure_id": 1076,
        "invoiced_quantity": "1.00",
        "line_extension_amount": "360000.00",
        "free_of_charge_indicator": false,
        "description": "ACTUALIZACION 2017",
        "code": "152",
        "type_item_identification_id": 4,
        "base_quantity": "1.00",
        "price_amount": "360000.00",
        "allowance_charges": [
            {
                "discount_id": 10,
                "charge_indicator": false,
                "allowance_charge_reason": "DESCUENTO",
                "amount": "0.00",
                "base_amount": "360000.00"
            }
        ],
        "tax_totals": [
            {
                "tax_id": 1,
                "tax_amount": "0.00",
                "percent": "0.00",
                "taxable_amount": "360000.00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "unit_measure_id": 1076,
        "invoiced_quantity": "1.00",
        "line_extension_amount": "60000.00",
        "free_of_charge_indicator": false,
        "description": "ACTUALIZACION DE SOFTWARE",
        "code": "27",
        "type_item_identification_id": 4,
        "base_quantity": "1.00",
        "price_amount": "60000.00",
        "allowance_charges": [
            {
                "discount_id": 10,
                "charge_indicator": false,
                "allowance_charge_reason": "DESCUENTO",
                "amount": "0.00",
                "base_amount": "60000.00"
            }
        ],
        "tax_totals": [
            {
                "tax_id": 1,
                "tax_amount": "0.00",
                "percent": "0.00",
                "taxable_amount": "60000.00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Pero me esta quedando asi:

```
    "credit_note_lines": [
    {
        "unit_measure_id": 1076,
        "invoiced_quantity": "1.00",
        "line_extension_amount": "360000.00",
        "free_of_charge_indicator": false,
        "description": "ACTUALIZACION 2017",
        "code": "152",
        "type_item_identification_id": 4,
        "base_quantity": "1.00",
        "price_amount": "360000.00",
        "allowance_charges": [
            {
                "discount_id": 10,
                "charge_indicator": false,
                "allowance_charge_reason": "Descuento Ggeneral",
                "amount": "0.00",
                "base_amount": "360000.00"
            }
        ],
        "tax_totals": [
            {
                "tax_id": 1,
                "tax_amount": "0.00",
                "percent": "0.00",
                "taxable_amount": "360000.00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "unit_measure_id": 1076,
        "invoiced_quantity": "1.00",
        "line_extension_amount": "60000.00",
        "free_of_charge_indicator": false,
        "description": "ACTUALIZACION DE SOFTWARE",
        "code": "27",
        "type_item_identification_id": 4,
        "base_quantity": "1.00",
        "price_amount": "60000.00",
        "allowance_charges": [
            {
                "discount_id": 10,
                "charge_indicator": false,
                "allowance_charge_reason": "Descuento Ggeneral",
                "amount": "0.00",
                "base_amount": "360000.00"
            },
            {
                "discount_id": 10,
                "charge_indicator": false,
                "allowance_charge_reason": "Descuento Ggeneral",
                "amount": "0.00",
                "base_amount": "60000.00"
            }
        ],
        "tax_totals": [
            {
                "tax_id": 1,
                "tax_amount": "0.00",
                "percent": "0.00",
                "taxable_amount": "360000.00"
            },
            {
                "tax_id": 1,
                "tax_amount": "0.00",
                "percent": "0.00",
                "taxable_amount": "60000.00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Como notaran... como lo estoy generando en el ultimo  producto se le agregan los valores del anterior producto en los elementos `allowance_charges` y `tax_totals`, la foma como lo estoy tratando de armar es la siguiente:

```
while ($rowDetail = $stmtDetail->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $allowance_charges['discount_id'] = 10;
  $allowance_charges['charge_indicator'] = false;
  $allowance_charges['allowance_charge_reason'] = "Descuento Ggeneral";
  $allowance_charges['amount'] = $rowDetail['cnd_discountVal'];
  $allowance_charges['base_amount'] = $rowDetail['cnd_unitValOrg'];

  $tax_totals['tax_id'] = intval($rowDetail['cnd_taxType']);
  $tax_totals['tax_amount'] = $rowDetail['cnd_taxVal'];
  $tax_totals['percent'] = $rowDetail['cnd_taxRate'];
  $tax_totals['taxable_amount'] = $rowDetail['cnd_subTotal'];

  $credit_note_lines['unit_measure_id'] = 1076;
  $credit_note_lines['invoiced_quantity'] = $rowDetail['cnd_quantity'];
  $credit_note_lines['line_extension_amount'] = $rowDetail['cnd_subTotal'];
  $credit_note_lines['free_of_charge_indicator'] = false;
  $credit_note_lines['description'] = $rowDetail['cnd_productName'];
  $credit_note_lines['code'] = $rowDetail['cnd_productCode'];
  $credit_note_lines['type_item_identification_id'] = 4;
  $credit_note_lines['base_quantity'] = $rowDetail['prd_TCantXUnidadEmpaque'];
  $credit_note_lines['price_amount'] = $rowDetail['cnd_subTotal'];
  $credit_note_lines['allowance_charges'][] = $allowance_charges;
  $credit_note_lines['tax_totals'][] = $tax_totals;

  $document['credit_note_lines'][] = $credit_note_lines;
}
```

El primer producto esta bien, a partir del segundo los valores aparecen duplicados, Como hago para que esto no suceda?

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor  no usas alias en en `SELECT` y luego llenas tu objeto sin más historias. Me explico: Si en tu objeto necesitas una propiedad `amount` con el valor de la columna `cnd_discountVal`, lo más simple es hacer esto: `SELECT amount AS cnd_discountVal ... FROM ...` y luego llenas el objeto sin hacer asignaciones manuales dentro del `while`. No sé si entiendes a lo que me refiero.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que inicializar el objeto `$credit_note_lines` al final de cada registro en el `while`

```
  unset($credit_note_lines);
```

puesto que `$credit_note_lines` lleva los valores de los productos y los entrega a `$document`

Algo obvio pero inicialmente no lo vi. Gracias por sus comentarios.